# SVN checkout forbidden with all the tools

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, svn

First I should say that I'm completely new to the **Maven** and **SVN**.

So I need really simple answers. After 2 days of googling and finding many vague answers all around the web, I still need this :

1. Download the source code of the cloudSim.
2. Compile it to a jar file.

---

On the [website](https://code.google.com/p/cloudsim/source/checkout) it says :

[image]

---

I've downloaded Apache Subversion command line tools from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/).

But when I try this :

`svn checkout http://cloudsim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ cloudsim-read-only`

I got this error :

[image]

I even tried [this](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/#), and again:
[image]

I've tried the SVN Repository of the Eclipse and again the results are the same.

Comment: Have you tried the http URL in your normal webbrowser? Do you get the same error message?

Comment: @TurboJ> Yes,exactly. It says it's not allowed in my country.

Comment: Your country is the subject of various embargoes, which means the administrator of the server doesn't allow anyone from an IP address that appears to be from your country to download code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about filtering or security applied by the hosting server

Comment: @MarkRotteveel> It is and it isn't. When I asked this here, I didn't know exactly where is the problem, and know at least I know the source of the problem. How could I ask it elsewhere even when I didn't know the origin of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It can be global permission-related problem (already resolved) at repo-side or *somehow* related with your side issue (proxy in-the-middle???), because now I got *from my side* expected

```
>svn ls http://cloudsim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
distribution/
documentation/
modules/
pom.xml
```

(`svn co` will be OK also)

Comment: I get exactly the same error message again, for `svn ls`. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @mok - only change country, sorry